# Slow searching groups in vim

Tags: regex, performance, search, vim

When I search for different strings in one execution, something like e.g.

```
/\(yadda\|schmadda\)
```

works fine. But this is extremely slow for long files compared to a standard search like `/yadda`.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You could do this but I want to see the file around the search pattern. I know this is also possible with grep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to searching via `/` is to use `:grep` and the `quickfix` list. Use `%` as a shortcut for the current filename.

```
:grep "yadda\\\|schmadda" %
```

Then navigate through the list via `:cnext` and `:cprev` or open the list in a window via `:copen`. I use [Unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which maps `]q` and `[q` to `:cnext` and `:cprev`.

For more speed especially across multiple files you can set Vim to use [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) instead of regular grep via `'grepprg'` option. e.g. `:set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor`.

If your system doesn't have grep or you would rather use Vim's flavored regexes you can use `:vimgrep` as an alternative to `:grep`. Example usage:

```
:vimgrep/\(yadda\|schmadda\)/ %
```

It should be noted that `:vimgrep` is usually slower than `:grep`.

See the following for more information:

```
:h :grep
:h quickfix
:h c_%
:h :cnext
:h :cope
:h 'grepprg'
:h :vimgrep
```

Comment: Using the syntax you are giving, I am getting errors: `/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `grep -n (outlet 2>&1| tee /tmp/v369365/2'

shell returned 2`

Comment: The search terms need to be quoted and escape the `|` (as well as escape it again as grep use `\|`). I Have updated the answer. You can imagine this command mirrors using `grep` on the command line so there will be similar escaping needs.

Comment: It works and adding the option `--binary-files=text` allows to use it for my big binary files. I guess one needs to get used to this style of searching though. Skipping to the list isn't as fast as simply pressing `n`. Nonetheless, thx @Peter!

Comment: I cannot recommend enough mapping `:cnext`/`:cprev` to something convenient. As stated in my answer, I use Tim Pope's Unimpaired plugin. I have also added a bit about using `:vimgrep` to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Vim 7.4 introduced a new, NFA-based regular expression engine. Though this is generally thought to be faster, there can be cases where it isn't.

You can try switching to the old engine via

```
:set regexpengine=1
```

You can also choose the engine inside the pattern via the special `\%#=1` atom.

PS: What exactly does *long files* mean? Long line lengths, large overall size?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using vim 7.0. Long files mean 250k lines à 66 Mb (binary).

Comment: OMG; why are you using an editor that was released in 2006 and is _very_ outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.4; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out something that hasn't been mentioned yet. While using grep for a use case like yours this would be a better workflow :

```
:grep yadda %
:grepadd schmadda %
```

Also note, there is also `:lgrep` and `:lgrepadd` which can used instead of `:grep` & `:grepadd` to use location lists (window local) instead of quickfix lists (global list), especially in your situation where you only want to search within the current file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I started using [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) after trying to find a solution. Ack.vim is fast.